# How I can access all fields of a http-request in an azure function (parse JSON in C#)?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

The microsoft azure is for me complete new programming topic.
Programming base language is C#.
I have to use Azure Funtion Http trigger from logic App (when new e-mail arrive).
I  give all possible data from the incoming e-mail in the log app to
to the azure function call.

Then I had first the problem nothing (no data) was requestable from the HttpRequest req.

I found out that C# .NetCore3.1 has problem with JSON-Object and get null-object back.
Then I build the project with  .NetCore2.1 and it worked generally.
I get correct informations like `req.Host` and i see a vaild JSON-object in data after such a call

```
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
```

But I don't know how I an parse the data like (from, to, subject, content, attachment,..) from the JSON-object.

I have tried many samples i found , but i fond nothing what worked, e.g. get null, exception,..

Can please someone here  post a small code snippet that works for azure function compiled with VS2017/2019 .NetCore2.1..

And other question is there eventually a way get the MimeMessage-obj direct from the http-request?
then i can get the informations direct from that object, but helping me with one of this both solution
where fine.

Otherwise I spilit the the JSoN Structure on myself to get the the informations on a very awkward way.
So I hope someone can help me.

```
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
        log.LogInformation($" host   : {req.Host}");

        string name = req.Query["name"];
        // read the contents of the posted data into a string
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        // use Json.NET to deserialize the posted JSON into a C# dynamic object
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

        name = name ?? data?.name;
```

For Example i had such a Json-content (is in dtaa after thes 2 lines of code):

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

Json-Content for a short email to parse (other request could differn in more ore lesser paramters(fields))

```
{ {
        "Conversion Id": "AAQkADRmZDAwMTMwLTI3MTMtNGI0Ny1iMzFiLTQzYWJiZDY0YWI1ZQAQAE2OZM06t0uQqpd9MuONKNQ=",
        "From": "test1@testxyz.com",
        "Has Attachment": false,
        "Internet Message Id": "<AM0PR07MB44178000A0B37882D6BC01D99ACC0@AM0PR07MB4417.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com>",
        "Is Html": false,
        "Is rRad": false,
        "Message Id": "AAMkADRmZDAwMTMwLTI3MTMtNGI0Ny1iMzFiLTQzYWJiZDY0YWI1ZQBGAAAAAAAvlJZPJxnGS4f6YWxh7zGsBwBnLziSnuG8R6h5C2SVmlYlAAHViSWpAACAWl3JfUo4SI7D5g-MgfEiAAJiPJQeAAA=",
        "Received Time": "2020-12-09T14:05:06+00:00",
        "Subject": "test1",
        "To": "test2@testxyz.com",
        "emailBody": "1234\r\n",
        "importance": "normal"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also fairly new and also had a similar problem. I realized that the only thing that works for me is, when I convert JSON to string and then just loop through it. I crop/trim the result for every variable and then convert it from string to whatever it has to be (part of object). It is practically a suicide with big cases like this. I am also interested in a better solution.

Comment: Please refer to the solution I provided below, if it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: If still have any problem about the code, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks it seems that it is not possible with using Newtonsoft.Json or similar libraries it is only possible iwth class binding. Is that Correct?
    public class EmailItem
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public Boolean Has_Attachment { get; set; }

    }

Comment: @ingo_ww Sorry for the delay reply, I didn't see your comment because you did not @me. For your question, yes, we can just implement it by create a class for email entity but can't do it just with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this requirement, you need to create an inner class in your function code to parse the request body to an object. Please refer to my code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            //dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            EmailItem data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailItem>(requestBody);

            log.LogInformation(data.From);
            log.LogInformation(data.Has_Attachment.ToString());

            return new OkObjectResult("completed");
        }
    }

    public class EmailItem
    {
        public string From { get; set; }

        public Boolean Has_Attachment { get; set; }

        //Add other fields which you want, please note add all of the fields which your request may contains in this inner class.
    }
}
```

As you mentioned `other request could differn in more ore lesser paramters(fields)`, so please add all of the fields which your request may contains in the `EmailItem` class.

By the way, the code I provided above was test with .net core 2.1 as you required. But I think the code can also work in .net core 3.1

Comment: I have long time not worked with azurefunction.
Is there in  the meanwhile a solution available that the data array  is not null if **.NetCore3.1** is used. at my last posting it only worked with **.Net2.1**?